# How can I automatically add a datestamp field to a java class marking a commit date

Tags: java, git, version-control, mercurial, versioning

I can't figure out a nice, succinct title for this question, so bear with me!

My overall goal is to have a variable in my source code which give the date, time, (and possibly commit id) of a class so that when exceptions get caught, I could output the error along with that said variable so I can easily track the source code version giving me the grief.

I'd like to accomplish one of two things. When I edit a java file such that mercurial or git picks up a change, I'd like for the class which got modified to get a new field:

```
public static final String commitTime = "yyyymmdd - hhmmss - <commitid>";
```

Or if inner class is too much, something appended to the bottom of the file such as:

```
public lass failname_stamp {
  public static final String commitTime = "yyyymmdd - hhmmss - <commitid>";
}
```

Or something to that effect.

This doesn't have to be specific to mercurial or git, however it would be a feature that ties in with them. So when a commit happens on a file, a process will run to add such data to the file itself.

I imagine such a tool would need to integrate with my IDE (eclipse and intelliJ) if not a 3rd party plugin for my mercurial or git instance.

I know I have seen source code files with comment fields at the top such as:

```
 /**
 * @since  1.2
 */
```

But I'd like something more thorough and specific and not relying on a human to manually update comments.

Comment: I tried Googling for similar situations and found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611171/how-to-insert-version-numbers-in-our-java-jars-that-a-user-can-access, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690419/build-and-version-numbering-for-java-projects-ant-cvs-hudson.  Both mention using properties files, instead of modifying the source.  I don't think these links do exactly what you want, but maybe they'd give you ideas about alternative approaches.

Comment: Why would you need that? Don't you know the overall version of your running code? Can't you then find the version of a particular source file that was included in that overall version? If not, then you have bigger problems.

Comment: @Andreas, what if I am not the only person using my code...

Comment: @ajb, Thanks for the links and ideas!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source itself cannot know the version being checked-in, unless you manually add some kind of version string - but that's both tedious and failure-prone.

However, I believe that you do not want this in the *source* code, but you want to generate this information at build time (as e.g. also different build environments might lead to different results) where you might generate a property file shipped with the object code.

I don't speak Java, but I solved that problem for a python project of mine:

1. When it is run from the repository, the code version is queried and used, e.g. for bug / crash reports [Querying hg for the checked-out version](https://kallithea.openttdcoop.org/nml/files/d69c8aaf6db61c5e394412e0729182a523805184/nml/version_info.py#L36)
2. When run outside a repository, the programme looks for a generated version file. I do ship my code bundles with such pre-generated version file; it's automatically generated and bundled with the otherwise un-touched code in the build script used on my compile farm. [Checking for presence of pre-generated version info, if code executed outside repository](https://kallithea.openttdcoop.org/nml/files/d69c8aaf6db61c5e394412e0729182a523805184/nml/version_info.py#L112)

I strongly suggest to employ a similar mechanism with your code: It's both, flexible and easy to use. Query for repository properties and fallback to use of a property file which you ship with your code bundles (and report 'unknown version' if neither is present)